# Report Builder Report from Stored Procedure returns empty tablix rows

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, report

I have a relatively simple stored procedure which is just a select statement from 2 joined tables, and has a single parameter.

Running it in SSMS returns, for example, 6 rows.

In Report Builder, I created a dataset from this SP, and I added the fields manually in the Fields tab, using the same names as in the SP.

I pull the fields to a tablix - which returns empty rows, but interestingly - 6 empty rows. So it works fine in SSMS and Query Designer - but nothing when executing.

I have tried creating a brand new report from scratch, and I have checked for white font on white background - no result.

Any clues what could be the reason?

thanks in advance,

PS Value property:
[image: Value Property]

Comment: Do you have anything in the Value property of each cell?   If so, can you post a screenshot?

Comment: I do have the field value yes. Added screenshot.